# MySQL select and compare to previous (next) value

Tags: sql, mysql, window-functions

I have the following SQL statement. It selects the visit count (`vc`) for a particular date (`vd`)

```
SELECT count(vid) vc, date(visitwhen) vd
FROM book_visit 
where date(visitwhen) >=date_sub(now(), interval 14 day)
group by vd
order by vd desc
```

This selects a range of data and the output would look like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "vc": 2,
            "vd": "2023-04-25"
        },
        {
            "vc": 1,
            "vd": "2023-04-24"
        },
        {
            "vc": 84,
            "vd": "2023-04-23"
        },
        {
            "vc": 17,
            "vd": "2023-04-21"
        },
        {
            "vc": 26,
            "vd": "2023-04-20"
        },
        {
            "vc": 1,
            "vd": "2023-04-19"
        },
        {
            "vc": 3,
            "vd": "2023-04-17"
        },
        {
            "vc": 18,
            "vd": "2023-04-16"
        },
        ....
```

What I would like to see is:

1. If the `vc` in one `vd` is larger/smaller than the previous or next `vc`/`vd`, I would also like to return a `+` (or `-`) or whatever that is indicative of a `vc` increase / decrease.

I can do this probably at the client side, but I would like to see if it is possible to do so in MySQL.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: you should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: You could do it with [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) or using the deprecated approach suggested in Ishan's answer. Given that this is solely display logic, you may be better off doing in your client app.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, if your MySQL supports:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT dt, num, IF(@oldnum IS NOT NULL, IF(@oldnum > num, '-', '+'), NULL) AS 'change', @oldnum := num
    FROM test_data
    ORDER BY dt
) t
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

This will result in something like this for some test data:

```
dt             num  change  @oldnum := num  
----------  ------  ------  ----------------
2023-04-10      15  -                     15
2023-04-09      32  +                     32
2023-04-08      14  +                     14
2023-04-07      13  -                     13
2023-04-06      83  +                     83
2023-04-05      35  -                     35
2023-04-04      63  -                     63
2023-04-03      93  +                     93
2023-04-02      34  -                     34
2023-04-01      59  (NULL)                59
```

First order by date - Keep `@oldnum = num` at the end, so that for the first record, it will be NULL.  From 2nd record onward, it will have the value of the previous record.  `IF` should be done before `@oldnum = num`. `IF` will decide what is the change in the current record in `num` as compared to previous record's `num` available as `oldnum`.

Yes, or, as @user1191247 has suggested, for MySQL 8+: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

```
SELECT dt, num, LAG(num) OVER w AS 'prev_num',
    IF(LAG(num) OVER w IS NOT NULL, IF(num > LAG(num) OVER w, '+', IF(num < LAG(num) OVER w, '-', '=')), NULL) AS 'change'
FROM test_data
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY dt)
ORDER BY dt DESC;

dt             num  prev_num  change
----------  ------  --------  --------
2023-04-10      15        32  -
2023-04-09      32        14  +
2023-04-08      14        13  +
2023-04-07      13        83  -
2023-04-06      83        35  +
2023-04-05      35        63  -
2023-04-04      63        93  -
2023-04-03      93        34  +
2023-04-02      34        59  -
2023-04-01      59    (NULL)  (NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current date criterion is [non-sargable](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/non-sargable-predicates/), as the server has to apply the `DATE()` function to the column value before it can be compared:

```sql
WHERE DATE(visitwhen) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

should be changed to:

```sql
WHERE visitwhen >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 DAY
```

and make sure you have an index on `visitwhen`.

You can use the [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) to get the previous row's value for a given expression:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(vid) vc, DATE(visitwhen) vd,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(vid) > LAG(COUNT(vid)) OVER w THEN '+'
        WHEN COUNT(vid) < LAG(COUNT(vid)) OVER w THEN '-'
        WHEN COUNT(vid) = LAG(COUNT(vid)) OVER w THEN 'nc'
    END AS `change`
FROM book_visit 
WHERE visitwhen >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 DAY
GROUP BY vd
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY DATE(visitwhen))
ORDER BY vd DESC;
```

Output:

| vc | vd | change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 2023-04-26 | + |
| 22 | 2023-04-25 | - |
| 24 | 2023-04-24 | - |
| 29 | 2023-04-23 | + |
| 21 | 2023-04-22 | - |
| 25 | 2023-04-21 | - |
| 29 | 2023-04-20 | + |
| 24 | 2023-04-19 | + |
| 22 | 2023-04-18 | - |
| 26 | 2023-04-17 | nc |
| 26 | 2023-04-16 | + |
| 21 | 2023-04-15 | - |
| 23 | 2023-04-14 | nc |
| 23 | 2023-04-13 | NULL |